# Querying by _id field in MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have been learning Angular and MongoDB and tried to implement some mock projects. In updating a document, I used `_id` field to find the document and update the other field, while doing in REST client I copy pasted the _id. Now, My question is how to implement this in Angular controller. I went through lot of documents but couldn't find any proper solution. Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

this is my update API

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Enterprise = mongoose.model('enterprise');

var updateEnterprise = function(req, res){

     Enterprise.findOneAndUpdate({"_id" : req.body._id},

        {$set: {"name" : req.body.name, 

        "email" : req.body.email}},

        {upsert: true},
        function(err, info){
            if(err){
                console.log("UPDATION FAILURE");
            } else {
                console.log(info);
                res.json(info);
                res.status(204);
            }

        });
} 
module.exports = {
    updateEnterprise:updateEnterprise
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API code is fine, just pass the _id as a string in request body from your angular code while calling API.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare the model file. First of all, include model file in `require('path/file')`